# Xamarin INetAddress.GetByName always throws exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, inetaddress

I'm trying to get the INetAddress with the following code:

```
try
{
  var address = InetAddress.GetByName ("google.com");
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (address);
}
catch (Java.Net.UnknownHostException)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("not working");
}
```

But it always prints "not working". I checked and my internet connection is fine. I don't know why this is happening. Thank's in advance.

Comment: Does the app have network permission?

Comment: Yes i have these 3 permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Have you solved it? It Throws me an exception: "Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException" tried to run it in RunOnUiThread.. not working...

Comment: Also having the same issue!

Comment: Try changing it to "www.google.com" or "http://www.google. com" and see if the result is any different

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by using `AsyncTask`.

here is my implementation

```
    public class ConnectionCheckAsyncTask : AsyncTask
    {
        private bool isInternetReachable()
        {
            try
            {
                var address = InetAddress.GetByName("google.com");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected override Object DoInBackground(params Object[] @params)
        {
            var res = isInternetReachable();
            return res;
        }
    }
```

to get result  you need to do next

```
    var task = new ConnectionCheckAsyncTask();
    task.Execute();
    var isReacheble = (bool)await task.GetAsync();
```

One more option to check inet connection. All you need is change `isInternetReachable` in `ConnectionCheckAsyncTask` with next code

```
        private bool isInternetReachable()
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
                Object objData = urlConnect.GetContent(new Class[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```